# How do I get CocoaPods to use the latest ruby version?

Tags: ruby, macos, cocoapods

My CocoaPods environment currently looks like this:

```
     CocoaPods : 1.4.0
      Ruby : ruby 2.5.0p0 (2017-12-25 revision 61468) [x86_64-darwin16]
  RubyGems : 2.7.3
      Host : Mac OS X 10.15.5 (19F101)
     Xcode : 11.5 (11E608c)
       Git : git version 2.24.3 (Apple Git-128)
Ruby lib dir : /Users/MacMini/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib
```

The problem is, on my computer ruby 2.5.0 uses openSSL 1.0.0, which was recently replaced with 1.1.1 during a software upgrade. So when I try to use CocoaPods I get this error:

```
Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
```

But ruby 2.7.1, which also in the .rbenv/versions directory next to ruby 2.5.0, has the proper dependencies. So how do I make CocoaPods use this later ruby version instead?

My PATH points to 2.7.1 and it's the version I get when I run ruby from the console.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The wrong Ruby version when working with cocoapod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39227718/the-wrong-ruby-version-when-working-with-cocoapod), or related to this: https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/wiki/Understanding-binstubs?

Answer (score 0):

I gave up trying to use CocoaPods from the command line and installed the CocoaPods application for Mac instead. That one works.